# Why i got yesterday at google app script?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script

im just learning google app script, and this problem really puzzling me. so, pretty please some help.

so, i am have this Google Sheet that collects responses from Google Form. This form has "Date" response on it, so i assume i always get the correct date format since it is automaticly generated ny sistem. But when i take the value in google app script, in

```
(DataObject[4].getDate()).toString()
```

it return yesterday value. so, if the value in Google sheet written "4/8/2022" i get "7" value in script app, instead of "8". (DataObject[4] is the variable where i store date value)

i already tried to add +1 in the script, like in

```
(DataObject[4].getDate()+1).toString()
```

but i got problem when the real date is "4/1/2022" the value become "32" (since march have 31 days).

is there something i did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change timezone in your script editor.

Click o the gear on the left hand side of the script editor and check the third box
[image]

Go back to the script, choose `appsscript.json` and change `timezone` as needed, for instance
[image]

Comment: thanks mr Mike, it was really helpful. hope you have a nice day